# Seeing New User data in Google Analytics before using the Tracking Code for mobile app. How is it possible?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I have not integrated GA SDK with my app, and yet I am seeing new user data in the Google Analytics Dashboard. Also, I found that all of the users are from Macintosh. How can this be solved?

Comment: I have found that above thing happen when GA tracking-id gets hacked, and that people involved in GA referral scam involve in those hacks.